# Random normal distubution

Tags: excel, csv, random, normal-distribution, visual-studio-macros

I have a csv File that looks like  :

```
subjects,       WeightedAverage,     WeightedStandardDev,    NumberofExams,
MathMark,              1.5,                 0.2,                   5,
PhysicMark,            1.6,                 0.4,                  10,
EnglishMark,            3,                  1.2,                  8,
PhiloMark,             8.2,                 1.5,                  9,
Others                 9.2,                 3.2,                  5,
```

I have another file where I need to generate data this way for each subject above :

For example for the subject `MathMark` the corresponding table should be :

```html
 NumberofExams                                     Mark                                                                              1                         =NORMINV(RAND(),WeightedAverage=1.5,WeightedStandardDev=0.2)
2                         =NORMINV(RAND(),WeightedAverage=1.5,WeightedStandardDev=0.2)
3                         =NORMINV(RAND(),WeightedAverage=1.5,WeightedStandardDev=0.2)
4                         =NORMINV(RAND(),WeightedAverage=1.5,WeightedStandardDev=0.2)
5                         =NORMINV(RAND(),WeightedAverage=1.5,WeightedStandardDev=0.2)
```

For example for the subject `EnglishMark` the corresponding table should be :

```
NumberofExams                                   Mark                                                                                            
1                          =NORMINV(RAND(),WeightedAverage=3,WeightedStandardDev=1.2)                                                2                           =NORMINV(RAND(),WeightedAverage=3,WeightedStandardDev=1.2)                                              3                          =NORMINV(RAND(),WeightedAverage=3,WeightedStandardDev=1.2)                               
4                          =NORMINV(RAND(),WeightedAverage=3,WeightedStandardDev=1.2)                                  
5                          =NORMINV(RAND(),WeightedAverage=3,WeightedStandardDev=1.2)             
6                          =NORMINV(RAND(),WeightedAverage=3,WeightedStandardDev=1.2)   
7                          =NORMINV(RAND(),WeightedAverage=3,WeightedStandardDev=1.2)
8                          =NORMINV(RAND(),WeightedAverage=3,WeightedStandardDev=1.2)
```

Want to produce `NumberofExams` random numbers with normal distribution (with `WeightedAverage`, `WeightedStandardDev`). How can I get these information from another `csv` file and calculate the random numbers needed in Excel. Any formula or Macro is appreciated.

Comment: and what's not working?

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux I am just wondering how to get data ( average , stdev ) from other columns or external files ?

Comment: Well, what about taking it from another cell? Say, `WeightedAverage=A20`

Comment: Totally agreed with @SeverinPappadeux , just past the csv data into another new sheet in the same file will work. || If you insist to link to another file.. save the csv as excel.. then link the cell.. It'll do just fine. ( :